# SAML token assertion validation

Tags: wif

I am using SAMLP CTP source for FSSO over SAML protocol. I would like to intercept SAML token on SP side before its convert by Saml2AuthenticationModule to the IClaimsPrincipal and before  SessionAuthenticationModule comes into action.

Why ?
I would like to have some validation of assertions. If everything is OK, WIF have to go as regular flow. If it is not, I have to avoid creation of Fed cookies and SessionAuthenticationModule session.

Other one solutions (but not so natural) is to log in user and then in code to verify assertions. If validation fails to log out user but only from this one application not from all apps in federation. I am not pretty sure how to accomplish this. I have tried with :

SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
  sam.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
  sam.SignOut();

but it not works.

Any of this scenarios will work for me. First will be better, but I will be satisfy with any in the moment.

Regards,
Rastko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to register a claims authentication manager in configuration. This will get called after token has been received and before the session gets created.

I wouldn't use the SAML2 CTP. I dont think this will ever get released.

Comment: Thank you leastprivilege,

[1] I was playing with ClaimsAuthenticationManager and it is strange to me that it is called before calling of my IdP not after that. Second,how to access token in method Authenticate, its signature is
'code' public override Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
so I get only claims principal.Assertions could be found only in Saml2SecurityToken.

[2] Instead of SAMLP CTP what would you suggest as an universal solution that is independent of chosen IDP ?

Tnx

Comment: The ClaimsAuthenticationManager is called after the security token handler has turned the token into claims. If that's ok for you - that's your extensibility point. If you need more control, you need to write your own token handler. Unfortunately I don't have a good answer for you. But using this CTP is no solution for anything strategic.